# What is making rsDriver from RSelenium take up so much RAM?

Tags: r, rselenium

I am running Chrome through rsDriver() from RSelenium in parallel and when I start my script each R-session takes about 300mb of RAM.

After a while, each session starts increasing the RAM and eventually crashes because of RAM failure.

I stopped the script when ram is 98% full and used the following code:

```
gc()
gc(rsdriver)
```

It does not help. I checked the environment size with

```
object_size(ls())
```

It returns that the environment is less than 1mb. The script I have running fetches data, but uploads it to a database. So it should not store anything.

How can I identify what is occupying this ram and fix it?
Some additional info:

I have 32gb of ram, should be enough.
I am aware of Docker, but irrelevant for this question